# Construct one line aggregate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I implement in pandas the following scenario

Input

> ```
>   a  b   c
> 0 10 90  0.2
> 1 20 150 2
> 2 30 -30 1.5
> ```

Getting only one total line of mean for Column A,B,C and max for Column C

Output

> ```
> mean mean mean max
>   a  b   c     c
> 0 20 70  1.23  2
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pd.concat` -

```
i = df.mean().to_frame().T
j = df[['c']].max().to_frame().T

pd.concat([i, j], 1, keys=['mean', 'max'])

   mean                  max
      a     b         c    c
0  20.0  70.0  1.233333  2.0
```

---

```
i
      a     b         c
0  20.0  70.0  1.233333

j
     c
0  2.0
```